# Rest API working well from Postman doesn't work from Salesforce

Tags: apex, rest, chatter-rest-api

I am beginner to REST APIs. I had a REST api used to login into some third party application. When used from Postman extension of Chrome it works well. However throws some generic error when used from Salesforce execute anonymous:

```
Httprequest request = new HttpRequest();
Http http = new Http();
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setEndpoint('http://someendpoint.com/service');
request.setTimeout(120000); 
String jsonString='{"login":"serviceusername","password":"passwordtologin","clientname":"101","clientappid":"202","clientappkey":"303"}';   
request.setBody(jsonString);          
System.debug('====='+request.getbody());     
//Making call to external REST API
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);  
System.debug('====='+response.getbody());
```

The only thing that I followed before using this api was including endpoint in remote site setting.I keep getting a generic response error saying invalid appkey/clientname. The reason I am saying its generic is because error remains same even when I use invalid username password.  Am I missing something ?

Postman Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: Invalid client id/app key in response body. That means the request didn't hit in proper format, as all parameter values were correct. They worked when used from Postman.

Comment: Could you screenshot postman parameters ,you can remove username and password and keep some dummy strings

Comment: Attached a screenshot from Postman. Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: So clearly you are sending form data via POSTMAN and JSON data via SFDC which is causing issue .Try sending JSON data via postman

Comment: Thank you Mohith. I would like to replicate same api in salesforce. Can you guide me how to do that? I mean can I set parameters similar to postman in apex.

Comment: can you set header as application/json and posting JSON to your external url via POSTMAN ?Sending via JSON from POSTMAN

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use the generate code button in postman, select the cUrl type. Take a look at the headers it generates on the working Postman version (the parameters with the -H) and add them to your apex using the setHeader method. 
Something like:

```
http.setHeader('content-type','application/Json');
```

Comment: Thank you JimRae. I was missing setting content-type header in my code. After setting content-type header to application/Json , things worked successfully.